# Scan Ciphers on FTPS port

Tags: ssl, ftps, cipher

I'm trying to remove RC4 ciphers per BEAST, but I'm having trouble verifying that there are ciphers available on my FTPS ports. NMAP returns the cert on the port, but doesn't say anything about the ciphers being used (nmap -p 9995 -T4 -A -v server) and SSL scan come back blank:

> Heartbleed:
>   TLS 1.2 not vulnerable to heartbleed
>   TLS 1.1 not vulnerable to heartbleed
>   TLS 1.0 not vulnerable to heartbleed
>
> Supported Server Cipher(s):

Is there another tool I can use? Am I missing a flag. We have qualys scanners, but I don't have access to them. Also the server is in our intranet so nothing on the public web will be able to hit it.

Thanks

Comment: Try with https://testssl.sh/

Comment: server:9995 doesn't seem a TLS/SSL enabled server. It doesn't recognize the FTPS port. That is a really cool tool though.

Comment: try `testssl.sh --starttls ftp <ftphost>.<tld>:9995`

Comment: Did you mistype `995`? There seem to be too many 9's in that port number.

Comment: testssl.sh --starttls ftp <ftphost>.<tld>:9995 worked. Thanks for your help.